# How to get Reaction Roles working in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get this functionality to work but I keep running into an issue with my reaction role. COuld it be that I am just using the wrong functions/methods? I would very much appreciate some help.

I am fairly new to discord bot dev and might be asking quite a silly question here, but your help would be very much appreciated!

Here is an example of my code!

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, Intents, GuildMember, ReactionEmoji } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client( 
  {
  partials: ['MESSAGE' , 'REACTON'],
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
const PREFIX = '$';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  //console.log(`[${message.author.tag}]: ${message.content}`);
  /* if (message.content === 'hello') {
            message.reply('https://media.giphy.com/media/KtnNLZVycYLdutzEm9/giphy.gif');
            //message.channel.send('https://media.giphy.com/media/KtnNLZVycYLdutzEm9/giphy.gif');
        }*/

  if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
      .trim()
      .substring(PREFIX.length)
      .split(/\s+/);
//KICK AND BAN 
    if (CMD_NAME === 'kick') {
      if (!message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS'))
        return message.reply('You do not have permissions to use that command');
      if (args.length === 0)
        return message.reply('Please provide the ID of the offender.');
      const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
      if (member) {
        member
          .kick()
          .then((member) => message.channel.send(`${member} was kicked.`))
          .catch((err) =>
            message.channel.send('I do not have permissions :( ')
          );
      } else {
        message.channel.send('That Member was not found');
      }
    } else if (CMD_NAME === 'ban') {
      if (!message.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS'))
        return message.reply('You do not have permissions to use that command');
      if (args.length === 0)
        return message.reply('Please provide the ID of the offender.');
      message.guild.members.ban(args[0]);

      try {
        const user = await message.guild.members.ban(args[0]);
        message.channel.send('User was banned successfully.');
        console.log(user);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send('An error occured. Either I do not have permission or the user was not found.')
      }
    }
  }
});

//Reactions Roles
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log('Whats Gud');
  const { name } = reaction.emoji;
  const member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
  if (reaction.message.id === '928504577475616819') {
    switch (name) {
      case '':
        member.roles.add('928503338683748352');
        break;
      case '':
        member.roles.add('928503897251782698');
        break;
      case '':
        member.roles.add('928503941430407168');
        break;
      case '️':
        member.roles.add('928503384561053847');
        break;
    }
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have the `MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD` [intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents) enabled in your code. You also don't seem to cache the message you need.

To fix this, you would first need to enable the intent which should make your intent declaration line look like

```
intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD],
```

And to cache the message you should add

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID)
channel.messages.cache.get(MESSAGE_ID)
```

To your ready event.

In the end you should have something like

```
const client = new Client(
{
    partials: ['MESSAGE' , 'REACTON'],
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
```

And

```
client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`);
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID)
    channel.messages.cache.get(MESSAGE_ID)
})
```